# Unable to deploy .ova file format, getting transfer failed when using ovftool

Tags: vmware, esxi, vmware-server

I'm getting a "transfer failed" error message. I tried manual and Ansible automation.

> "Transfer Failed",
>   "Error: File (SLESOS-disk1.vmdk) could not be found.",
>   "Completed with errors"]}